# App is running even though disabled! Why?

Tags: applications

I did:

```
pm disable com.android.systemui
```

I get:

```
pm list packages -d
package:com.android.systemui
```

So it is disabled. Still I get:

```
ps | grep systemui                                            
u0_a71    2053  1183  462960 27552 ffffffff 40089a40 S com.android.systemui
```

so it is still running, even if I kill it, it restarts! How can it both be running and be disabled at the same time?

Comment: It's a bad idea to disable SystemUI.

Comment: Why? What can happen except the loss of navigation bar etc?

Comment: Pretty much that. I found your comment on the related SO question.

Comment: never ever disable system UI strange things may happen as it is required by the entire system so that you can interact with your device as @Gokul NC said

Answer (score 2):

SystemUI.apk is an System app which needs to be always running to provide the Android UI as you know, like Navigation bar, Status Bar, even Wallpapers, and lots more ....

It's a very bad idea disabling it. Even if you disable it, it'll just restart.
If you remove it, your phone won't be having an UI.

> How can it both be running and be disabled at the same time?

As far as the question is concerned, I think the current instance of the app will be running eventhough you disable waiting for the effect to take place on reboot.
But Android may not allow SystemUI being disabled during boot, by forcibly starting the app and its services.

If you are a developer/debugger and really want to disable it for some reason, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055413/can-i-disable-systemui-from-within-my-android-app

I think you can also Freeze it using apps like Link2SD :)

Answer (score 0):

A few apps like these are necessary to run the OS. So, no matter how hard you try, this will start again and again. In fact, this default setting is just to prevent your device from getting bricked or behaving abnormally.